# Is it possible hide the Publish button in command menu of a document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, json-formatting

I would like to hide the publish button in the command bar on a document library.
I want to do this because i don't want users to use the publish button. I already have a workflow that is doing it.
I looked at using json formatting but can't see any valid key for it
Any thoughts or ideas will be appreciated

Comment: Not possible using JSON formatting yet. Are you using approval/check-in checkout on documents?

Comment: Ok thanks.Im not using check in check out.Why are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to hide the publish button in the image below?

[image]
You can hide it by setting: Library setting-> Versioning settings ->select Create major versions under Document Version History

Ouput（publish button is hidden）：
[image]

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "**√**" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.